# Derivation of the Irish surname Hamil (is it from Hamuel in the bible)?

Tags: surnames, ireland

My last name is Hamil and my family genealogy comes from Ireland.

An individual who researched the family states that Hamil is a variation of the Hamuel found in the Bible who is a descendant of Judah.

Is there any way to verify this information?

There are no citations in the resource I have.

Answer (score 3):

The Oxford Names Companion (which has a UK focus, not an Irish one) gives the Hammill surname as either (1) Scots (originally Norman) derived from somebody who came from Haineville or Henneville in Manche, or (2) English, derived from the nickname for a scarred or maimed person, from the Middle/Old English *hamel*: mutilated, crooked.

Either derivation *might* apply in your case, but there is also the original Irish name: Ó hAdhmaill (pronounced Oh–ham-will) or Ó hAghmaill, ([part of the Cenél mBinnigh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branches_of_the_Cen%C3%A9l_nE%C3%B3gain)) which was anglicised as (among others) Hammil.

So you have some choices but no support for the derivation from Hamuel. Which derivation is most likely will depend on what else you know about your Irish heritage.

Answer (score 0):

With the family history book that you refer to not being published, it makes things a little hard to research, but my quick search just now suggests two very different possible origins for your surname in [The Internet Surname Database](https://www.surnamedb.com/Surname/Hamil):

> This interesting and unusual surname has two possible sources, the
>   first being Scottish but also ultimately of Norman origin, and a
>   locational name from the place called "Haineville" or "Henneville" in
>   Manche.